# Growth factor problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I am trying without success to understand how two formulae in appendix B of [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/508/2/483/pdf/38220.pdf) are derived.

Equation B1 is an equation for perturbations, obtained from regular perturbation theory: $$\ddot{\delta} + 2\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\dot{\delta} = 4\pi G \rho \delta$$ where the dot means derivative with respect to time $t$.

I'm happy with equations B2 and B3. which are [Friedman equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) in general relativity for a cosmology where the universe is expanding, and I don't have any problems with B4 to B6. But I don't understand how B1 (above), B5 and B6: $$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\ddot{a}a}{\dot{a}^2} = -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2}w(1 - \Omega)\\
\frac{d\Omega}{d \ln a} = 3w(1 - \Omega)\Omega
\end{eqnarray}$$ allow us to derive B7: $$\frac{d^2 \ln \delta}{d \ln a^2} + \left(\frac{d \ln \delta}{d \ln a}\right)^2 + \frac{d \ln \delta}{d \ln a}\left[\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}w(1 - \Omega)\right] = \frac{3}{2}\Omega$$

or how defining $\alpha$ as $\Omega^\alpha \equiv \frac{d \ln \delta}{d \ln a}$ allows us to combine B6 and B7 to get B10: $$3w(1-\Omega)\Omega\ln\Omega\frac{d\alpha}{d\Omega} - 3w\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Omega + \Omega^\alpha - \frac{3}{2}\Omega^{1-\alpha} + 3w\alpha - \frac{3}{2}w + \frac{1}{2} = 0$$

What am I missing?

Comment: Most people will downvote this question because they need to do too much effort to figure out what you mean. Please consider adding all necessary information in one question. You could add print screens of the necessary parts out of the pdf.

Comment: I've edited in the relevant formulae, but it would be helpful to have more context in terms of what you've tried and how far you get. E.g. is $\frac{d\ln g}{dt} = \frac{\dot{g}}{g}$ a useful hint to get you started, or are you already way beyond that?

Comment: @DavidK, in my experience it is never a good idea to suggest to someone new to the SE network that a question would be a better fit on a different site in the network *unless* you explicitly mention that it can be migrated by flagging and asking a moderator to do it. Otherwise you end up with cross-posts and much irritation all round. But in this case, it seems to be pure algebraic manipulation, so I think it's a better fit here.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, that's good advice. I have deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: With the formulas, this question seems more on-topic than when it sent us to look at a PDF somewhere.

Comment: Hello, thank you Peter for editing in a more friendly post, I have tryied to change variable from t to $ln a$ but without succes.I have used $\frac{d ln a}{dt}=H(t)$ and $a=\frac{1}{z+1}$

Comment: I have managed to derive B7 but i am still missing something with B10.